# ImageView height always returns zero in android

Tags: android

I know this is kind of a duplicate but the answers for other question didn't help me. always my `ImageView` height returns zero. here is what I tried:

```
dart.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
        int finalHeight = dart.getMeasuredHeight();
        int finalWidth = dart.getMeasuredWidth();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+finalHeight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

ALSO -

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    height = dart.getHeight();
    width = dart.getWidth();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+height,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And I also tried `dart.getHeight()` inside the `onCreate` but I understood it can't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `addonPreDrawListener` to `ViewTreeObserver` and call  `dart.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);` in your `onPreDraw()` method

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            dart.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalHeight = dart.getMeasuredHeight();
            finalWidth = dart.getMeasuredWidth();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this," "+finalHeight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: it shows the correct height, but I want to use it in my onCreate method, can it be done? if I am using it outside the onPreDraw() it is still zero..